# How to size the swing app such that the borderline of the JFrame always touches the taskbar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to prevent my app from resizing and have done the following (based on valuable suggestions from stackoverflow):

```
 MyFrame frame = new MyFrame("LabelTest");
 frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setResizable(false);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This works fine...but once I click on the title bar the application becomes :[image]
and is no longer resizable.

How does one disable action on title bar?

I have the done the following to stretch out my application :

```
class SwingApplication
  {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame("LabelTest");

        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setVisible(true);    // FIRST visible = true
        frame.setResizable(false); // THEN  resizable = false
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

**Output 1 :**

[image]

But once i minimize and restore the application ,it takes up the entire screen.Any fix to make the application appear as in *Output 1*?

After I minimize and restore ,**Output 2** :

[image]

Comment: Call resizable before setVisible .. setVisible should be the last statement

Comment: @nachokk ...if put setVisible to be the last statement..the app initially starts just as the image i showed above..but i want it maximized

Comment: ^ Note that it's apparent from the answer by @CyrilleKa in that question that the behavior you are asking about is a Windows 7 quirk and not particularly solvable.

Comment: try `setResizable` before `setExtendedState`. `setResizable` may call pack or something weird like that.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/); don't forget `pack()` and [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Is this specific to Windows?

Comment: Wait, so your problem is that when you first run the application, it appears fine, but when you minimize the screen and then restore it back, it appears bigger than usual?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to prevent resizing?

Comment: @trashgod yeah its working fine in ubuntu(linux)...yes its specific to windows ..

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick if this is the behavior the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the proper way to avoid this situation, here s simple hack to keep the screen size just big enough to avoid being hidden by the tool bar. I just set the height a little less than the screen size.  Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but you can give it a try.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class SwingApplication {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelTest");

        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getScreenSize();

        int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
        Dimension newDim = new Dimension(width, height - 40);

        frame.setSize(newDim);

        frame.setVisible(true); // FIRST visible = true
        frame.setResizable(false); // THEN resizable = false
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```